$\operatorname{GL}_n(K)$-subrepresentations of $\operatorname{Sym}^d K^n$ in positive characteristic
Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, $G = \operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ and $V = K^n$ the standard representation. It is well-known that the symmetric algebra powers
$$S_d = \operatorname{Sym}^d(V^*) = K[x_1,\dots,x_n]_d$$
are irreducible representations of $G$ in characteristic $0$. The same conclusion holds true if $p:=\operatorname{char}(K)>d$ (as it is often the case), but it fails if $p \leq d$. For example if $p=d=2$, then $S_2$ has a (unique) non-trivial subrepresentation; the image of the Frobenius $(S_1)^2 = \langle x_1^2,\dots,x_n^2\rangle_K$. More generally, one can build examples such as $(S_k)^{p^e} \subsetneq S_d$ (for $k p^e = d$) in characteristic $p$.
Any invariant subspace $W \subseteq S_d$ must have a basis of monomials (since it is also invariant by the standard torus $(K^\times)^n)$. If $x_1^{a_1}\dotsm x_n^{a_n} \in W$, then $x_1^{b_1}x_2^{b_2+a_2}\dotsm x_n^{a_n+b_n} \in W$ for $b_1+\dots+b_n = a_1$ as long as $p \nmid\binom{a_1}{b_1,\dots,b_n}$: Just take the substitution
$$
x_1 \mapsto x_1+\dots+x_n, \qquad x_i \mapsto x_i,\quad i>1.
$$
and collect terms by monomiality. Of course, any permutation of indices will also give a monomial in $W$. This suggests that the combinatorics/divisibilities of the exponents which occur play an important role in understanding $W$.
Question: For general $d\geq p$, is there a nice classification of the invariant subspaces of $S_d$? Do they all "come from Frobenius"? Are they nested in each other?
I'm relatively new to representation theory, so sorry if this is a naive question :D Thank you for your considerations!
